# Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - How to disable pop-ups boxes

Tags: visual-studio, editor, intellisense, modalpopup

I have seen this question asked many times, however the answers do not seem to apply to Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit): how can I disable the pop-up boxes that appear whenever you hover over variables or functions? This functionality is enabled by default and is incredibly annoying.

Note that I am not referring to auto-completion, just the pop-ups when hovering.

In the hours I have spent researching this problem I have seen references to File/Preferences, the '%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json' file and many other suggestions, but none seem to apply to this version of Studio.

I am coding in C# however I believe this is a problem with the editor in all languages.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about Tooltips?  There is no standard way in the UI, but Mads Kristiansen did make an extension to do this.  The bad news is he does not appear to have updated it for VS 2022.  The good news is that the code is [available online](https://github.com/madskristensen/ToggleQuickInfo):

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's ToolTips. Unfortunately with Mads Kristiansen's Toggle_Editor_Tooltips_v1.0.7 I get the error "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."

Comment: Yeah I think you would probably need to build his code yourself.  I've never built my own extension before (nor installed one I personally built) but as I understand it, it's not supposed to be too hard.  Mads builds them all the time.  Might want to do a bit read of reading on how to do that

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will. I just can't believe that anyone can concentrate on code with all the tooltip noise.

Comment: Support for 2022 has been added now and it works.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2022 Community and the "Toggle Editor Tooltips" v1.0.9 extension works like a charm. Thanks Mads!

Answer (score 0):

For mac;

1. Click to "VİSUAL STUDIO" (on top left corner),
2. Click "Extensions",
3. Click to "Installed" button on top middle,
4. Disable z.Ned Core Debugger"